# Does canceling copying files process leave partially copied/uncopied files?

Tags: files, copy

I managed to mount a corrupted encrypted hd using a bootable ubuntu usb stick and I was copying the files from it to an external disk.

The process takes hours and hours and hours and hours and hours. Unfortunately by mistake I cancelled the copying process. I started it again applying to all the `Merge folders` option and `Skip` if files with the same name are found.

My question is: might stopping the copying process have left half-copied (hence invalid) files that should be checked? Or does canceling the process remove partial-copied data?

Comment: I have found that a cancelled (^C) copy can leave the last file partially copied (but not always), so I've got in the habit of checking/erasing the last copied (IF it was in the process of an actual copy at the moment I ^C).  As I `cp -p`; the date/time will be the moment of copy instead of preserved - a clue that makes such files easy to find & erase too.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a cancelled (^C) copy can leave the last file partially copied (but not always), so I've got in the habit of checking/erasing the last copied (IF it was in the process of an actual copy at the moment I ^C).

As I `cp -p`  (ie. preserve time/date/attributes) ; the date/time will be the moment of copy instead of preserved - a clue that makes such files easy to find & erase too if you forget immediately (using `find`).

*This may depend on file-system used, as well as local files or network (nfs)*

Comment: The copying process was started with the graphical interface and stopped  from the window that appears when clicking on the sort of pie chart in Nautilus, not with the terminal

Comment: I can't speak to gui operated copies, as I always use terminal (unless it's minor such as new pictures from a camera).  But I suspect the result is the same (I just don't know sorry).

Comment: Ok thank you anyway. Just to let u know after I clicked cancel I have seen something like "canceling copying"... And it took a while so maybe it was removing unfinished file. I LL check anyway